# Mostrar usuarios con Angular de la página 2 al clickear en el btn - Rest-API(reqres.in)

Tags: angular

estoy iniciando con Angular, agradecería puedan orientarme un poco.

Los datos que vienen en la API son los primeros 6 usuarios ("page": 1), lo que intento es cuando presione en el botón 2 ( Componente paginación ) muestre los otros 6, cambiando así a "page": 2.

Cualquier ayuda y/o crítica es bien recibido.

```
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "George",
            "last_name": "Bluth",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"
        }
          ...
        
}
```

Lo que tengo en mi service:

```
export class UserService {

  private serviceUrl: string = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';
  public userList : User[] = [];
  public totalPages: number = 1;
  public numberPage: number = 1;
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  get AllUsers() {

    let params = new HttpParams()
      .set("page", this.numberPage);

   return  this.http.get<UserResponse>(`${this.serviceUrl}`, { params })
      .pipe(
        map( resp => {{
          this.userList = resp.data;
          this.totalPages = resp.total_pages;
          this.numberPage = resp.page;
        }})
      )
  }
```

**Componente Lista de Usuario**

Crea la tabla con los 6 primeros usuarios que trae la API.

```
export class ListUsersComponent implements OnInit{
  
  constructor( private usersService: UserService ){}

  @Input()
  public usersList: User[] = [];
  //public totalPage : number = 1;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usersService.AllUsers.subscribe();
  }

  
}
```

**Componente "Paginación"**

Este componente genera 2 botones dinámicos, en base al número de páginas obtiene la respuesta a la API, la idea es cuando clickee en el botón 2, muestre los 6 siguientes.

```
    export class PaginationComponent {
    
      @Input()
      public totalPages: number = 1;
    
    
      constructor(private usersService: UserService) { }
    
    
      elementClicked(event: any) {
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
        var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
        var value = parseInt(idAttr.nodeValue);
    
        console.log(value)
    
      }


  createRange(number: number) {
    // return new Array(number)
    return new Array(number).fill(0)
      .map((n, index) => index + 1);

  }
}
```

Lo que tengo en mi HomePage

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col p-3">
            <h1 class="text-white text-center w-100">{{ title | titlecase }}</h1>
            <app-list-users [usersList]="usersList"></app-list-users>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col">
            <!-- Pagination  -->
            <app-pagination-users 
                [totalPages]="totalPages">   
            </app-pagination-users>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```